# Can't set value for 'Environment' field in Jira using Jira REST Java Client

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am not seeing any `issueBuilder` *method* to set value for 'Environment' field in 'issue creation'. Environment field is not hidden. I can see it on my 'Create issue' screen.

Comment: what's the type of custom field Environment ? What do you get in response ? there is usually clue what's the problem

Comment: 1.I'm using jira-rest-java-client-2.0.0-m2.jar .not using any http get/post. I'm using factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication. successful when I'm creating issue of type 'Story' as it is not having the Environment field.With above code, I am trying to create a issue of type 'Bug' which needs 'Environment' as a mandatory field. 
So I'm not seeing any system defined method for Environment like we've for Description SetDescription("Descvalue");
3. 'Environment' is a system field and as per our requirement it is made as mandatory field.  Error message : 'Environment is required to create issue'

Comment: Did you find any resolution, I'm trying to get it. I can not see this here: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e847

Answer (score 1):

The environment field is accessible upon creation using the REST API, under the "fields" group:
[JIRA 6.4.12 REST API Documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5089)

So the "fields" array looks like this in PHP:

```
"fields" => array(
    "project" => array("key" => 'WHATEVER'),
    "summary" => $summary,
    "description" => $description,
    "environment" => $environment,
    "issuetype" => array("id" => $issueType)
)
```

Make sure that the "environment' field is part of your default screen for that project. If not, the issue creation will fail.

Answer (score 1):

There are no special method for "environment" field in builder, but you can use method setFieldValue, f.e.: `builder.setFieldValue("environment", "Some value")`